# Read table header field value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, datagrid, html-table, double-click, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a grid. on double clicking the grid, I need to get the field values of the table..

Grid code:

```
<div class="claro" id="sdsfs" name="dataGrid" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'xy','inner__sdsfs')" ondblclick="editDataGridResponse(this.id)" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="height: 200px; left: 58px; position: absolute; top: 51px; width: 950px;">
     <table class="claro" dojotype="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="inner__sdsfs" rowselector="10px" style="height: 95%; width: 95%;">
          <thead>
               <tr>
                    <th field="Column1" width="100px">
                         Column1
                    </th>
                    <th field="Column2" width="100px">
                         Column2
                    </th>
                    <th field="Column3" width="100px">
                         Column3
                    </th>
                    <th field="Column4" width="100px">
                         Column4
                    </th>
                    <th field="Column5" width="100px">
                         Column5
                    </th>
               </tr>
          </thead>
     </table>
     <input id="hidden__sdsfs" name="dataGrid" style="display:none;" type="hidden">
</div>
```

I tried the below function. but its not working.

```
 editDataGridResponse():



function editDataGridResponse(_sgridID){
    var tableID = document.getElementById("inner__"+_sgridID);
    for(var i=0; i<tableID.rows[0].length; i++){
                    alert(tableID.rows[0].field);
                }
   }
```

Comment: `alert(tableID.rows[0].cells[i].textContent);`

Comment: am getting error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: Will the field value and the header content value is always the same?

Comment: i got the issue.. since the grid is dojo type, the function is not working. for html grid/table, the function returning the field values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function editDataGridResponse(_sgridID){
    var tableID = document.getElementById("inner__"+_sgridID);
    for(var i=0; i<tableID.rows[0].cells.length; i++){
         alert(tableID.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: i got the issue.. since the grid is dojo type, the function is not working. for html grid/table, the function returning the field values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function editDataGridResponse(_sgridID){
    var tableID = document.getElementById("inner__"+_sgridID);
    if (tableID)
    {
        for (var j= 0; j < tableID.rows.length; j++)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<tableID.rows[j].cells.length; i++){
                        alert(tableID.rows[j].cells[i].field);
                    }
        }
    }
    else
      alert("Table Id " + "inner__"+_sgridID + " Wrong");
  }
```

Comment: Plz Check with my if condition.